# Django object related categories and subcategories shown in form

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

maybe somebody can help me, I use Django with the following models.py:

```
    class FilterCategory(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.name

    class FilterValue(models.Model):
        category = models.ForeignKey(FilterCategory)
        value = models.CharField(max_length=50)


    class Video(models.Model):
        title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
        filters = models.ManyToManyField(FilterValue, blank=True)
```

Now what I need is to show HTML form in template where user can choose filters for Video in separate fields, so lets say in Box A User can choose one or more filters from Category A

Does anybody have ideas what is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a model form with two [ModelChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField)s and pass them with a queryset containig filters in each category. Then you override form's `save` method where you can use cleaned form data to add filters to Video model.